# CORS fails on http-server

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I am using a simple http-server while developing a javascript app in which there are with several ajax requests to external APIs.  I started the server with "http-server --cors" via CLI, but still get "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" errors.  This occurs whether or not the external API requires a user key/pre-flight, such as:

```
var url = "http://api.rgrta.com/";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("api_key","d4f...3f5");
    },
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
})
.done(function(jsonData) {
    console.log("*** ajax success ***");
    callbackFunc();

    function callbackFunc() {
        console.log("callbackFunc");
    }
});
```

I've seen solutions involving express app.js configurations.  Is node/express the only way to define request headers properly?  What is the best way to set up my local http-server when developing for CORS-enabled API calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a server side code snippet which you have provided, rather its client side code which runs  over browser, and hence cross origin errors would occur if the target api has **cors** turned off, the solution in that case would be to use a proxy.

Also enabling cors on simple http server means that you are allowing your website content to be accessed elsewhere by others.

Answer (score -1):

While you are developing, you may want to use a browser extension that allows CORS to be enabled and disabled easily, such as this one for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: That is not a suitable SO answer, it is a recommendation to an external tool.